# Adding onComplete handler after TweenMax object created?

Tags: javascript, gsap

I want to add an onComplete handler after I create my TweenMax object but I can't find a way to do it.  How would I go about this?

Just to clarify I **do not** want to do this:

```
TweenMax.to(obj, 0.5, { x: 100, onComplete: myFunc });
```

But instead I want to do something like this:

```
var tween = TweenMax.to(obj, 0.5, { x: 100 });
tween.onComplete = myFunc; //  Or however you do this...
```

Using `TweenMax.set(obj, { onComplete: myFunc });` fires the event instantly.
I think I have to dig into the TweenMax object to find the onComplete reference but I can't find it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `eventCallback`, like so

```
var tween = TweenMax.to(obj, 0.5, { x: 100 });
tween.eventCallback("onComplete", myFunc, ["param1","param2"]);
```

I got it from here http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenLite/eventCallback/